# Android How to change data of Textview by clicking on button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sdk

First of all, the app looks like this.

[image: App design]

How to make - if I click on Add, on its column the textview is updated with value + 1?

I'm creating TextView and Button in a Loop;

```
for(int i = 0;i < playercountint; i++)
{
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(100/playercountint)));
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
TextView tt = new TextView(this);
            tt.setText("0");
            tt.setTextSize(14);
            tt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


            Button btadd = new Button(this);
            btadd.setText("Add");
            btadd.setId(2);


            btadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     ????? what here?
                 }
             });
}
```

What should be written in onClick function , so only TextView value which is in buttons column is changed.

There is one outer LinearLayout which is horizontally oriented, and those which are created within a loop is vertical Linear Layouts.

Maybe i should create a template for 1 loop iteration?

Answer (score 2):

First make your textview `final` and them set it's value in onClick

```
for(int i = 0;i < playercountint; i++)
{
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(100/playercountint)));
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
final TextView tt = new TextView(this);
            tt.setText("0");
            tt.setTextSize(14);
            tt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


            Button btadd = new Button(this);
            btadd.setText("Add");
            btadd.setId(2);


            btadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    tt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tt.getText())+1));
                 }
             });
}
```

You can write one function that returns linearlayout:

```
public View getPlayerView(){
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(100/playercountint)));
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    final TextView tt = new TextView(this);
                tt.setText("0");
                tt.setTextSize(14);
                tt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


                Button btadd = new Button(this);
                btadd.setText("Add");
                btadd.setId(2);


                btadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                        tt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tt.getText())+1));
                     }
                 });
           layout.add(tt);
           layout.add(btadd);
     return layout;
}
```

Call this function in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
tt.setText("something");
tt.invalidate();
```

my bad I didn't even notice it was a for loop uh you need to hold a reference to the text view.. make your textview final

Comment: I believe you have to make the textView final before you put it into the onClick function.

Comment: I guess you can't just like reference to an object created before, but somehow need to find it.
Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot refer to a non-final variable tt inside an inner class defined in a different method

Answer (score 1):

```
tt.setText(Integer.parse(tt.getText().toString()) + 1);
```

But, I strongly recommend you design UI (layout) in the *.xml file!
See more: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Yeah, but my layout depends on playercount, any suggestions?
I'm new to Android Developping

Comment: Integer.parseInt(...);

Comment: this wont work as tt.setText(<INT>) expects the resource id of the string. You must set string instead

Comment: @waplet: there is no problem, player count is not take effect in UI, it's just data. Here is algorithm for your case: first, you get the current number by tt.getText().toString(), then convert it to int by Integer.parseInt(String str), incrase it, then tt.setText(String.valueof(Int int)). *Hint: if you use eclipse, type Ctrl+space for suggestion about code. Gluck!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your `TextView` with an unique `id` (.setId(...)). Having this, in your `onClick` method simply use something like this:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
final String cur_text = tv.getText();
Integer plus_one = Integer.valueOf(cur_text);
plus_one++;
tv.setText(plus_one.toString());
```

Didn't try it but should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int counter = 0;

    btn_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter ++;
            tv_Display.setText("Your Total is : " + counter);

            }
        });
```